# ajax request with same data to server from user, getting issue in request format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

For two request same children variable got assigned but format of request getting changed for children

I have used two different formats to send data on ajax has below

Requirement:-
In first request also children to be like 2nd request

1st Request:-

given data in ajax:-

```
data: 'bid='+ Bid +"&"+sharewith+"&"+"children"+children,
```

on server request:

```
"GET /buildknowledge/sharing?bid=172&&children[]173,174 HTTP/1.1" 500 14113
```

2nd Request:-

given data in ajax

```
$.get('?operation=delete_node', {'id': data.node.id,'children':children})
```

on server request:

```
"GET /buildknowledge/? 
operation=delete_node&id=172&children%5B%5D=173&children%5B%5D=174 HTTP/1.1" 200 22409
```

Comment: I have no idea what your trying to say I'm afraid

Comment: Nope, no better really. Have a read though [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: question got updated

Comment: Yeah, I saw, still no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to manually construct the query string. If you are using jQuery then make use of its helper functions:

[.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

[.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)